# Global method not being called unless I have a window.setTimeout of 1000 ms around the call

Tags: javascript, html, angular, global-variables, settimeout

I have an index.html file and in it I have a script tag that's receiving a callback from google maps. If I remove the timeout, I get this error.

> Uncaught TypeError TypeError: window.globalMethod is not a function

My 'globalMethod' is located in a directive being used on the page and I would assume maybe the directive's constructor isn't loaded, but I'm running the google maps script after `<app-root></app-root>` so you would think it would find `window.globalMethod()`?

I tried it with 100, but that doesn't seem to be long enough and still receive the error.

Here is index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  // left out other head tags for brevity
  <script>
    function initPlaces() {
      // won't run if I remove window.setTimeout
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        window.globalMethod();
      }, 1000);

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=secret-key&libraries=places&callback=initPlaces" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh, I missed that that was a function. I don't think my comment is relevant.

Comment: Try adding type="module" on the script tag in your head

Comment: that doesn't do anything...